# Related Posts not related, what does the algorithm look for?

Tags: support, related-questions, algorithm

I've been noticing that a lot of the time the "Related" section on the right side are not often related to the question.

Do we know how this algorithm works? It seems like it could use an update.

I see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) all the time at the top of the list. For example, on [How to Add/Remove Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777367/how-to-add-remove-views) it's at the top, but it's not related in any way, except it has the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

Comment: That sounds like it goes by tag, and possibly similar words...